# C++ specialized template function receiving literal string

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, string-literals

I am writting a template method which has many specializations.

```
class FieldValue
{
public:
   ...
   template< typename T >
   void Set( const T& value );
   ...
};
```

One of them is:

```
template <>
void FieldValue::Set< const char* >( const char* const& value )
{
   ...
}
```

But when I try to call

```
FieldValue fieldValue;
fieldValue.Set( "literal string" );
```

it expects an specialization for `const char[14]` which is the length of `"literal string"`, not a `const char*`

Is there any work around this without the need to cast it to `const char*`?

***UPDATE***

After Rakete1111's recommendation, that's what I did:

```
class FieldValue
{
public:
   ...
   template< typename T >
   void Set( const T& value );

   template< std::size_t N >
   void Set( const char( &value )[ N ] )
   {
     Set( static_cast< const char* >( value ) );
   }
   ...
};
```

This will end up calling the `const char*` specialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were asking this for a class, I would have answered that you can use partial specialization:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct Foo<const char (&)[N]> {};
```

But that doesn't work for function templates. Instead, you can overload them:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void FieldValue::Set(const char (&Value)[N]) {}
```